# How can I get all the file names of documents in my sandbox?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

However I am clueless as to how to get all the files names and assign them to an array?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSFileManager has a method called [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) that returns an array of all the files in that directory.

You can use it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if([paths count] > 0)
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *documentArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not get list of documents in directory, error = %@",error);
    }
}
```

The `documentsArray` object will contain a list of all the files in that directory.

Answer (score 4):

Use NSFileManager's [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager* fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSArray* documentsArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
    [documentsArray count];
```

Is another way of doing this for those with a different set up.